# Keep VLOOKUP range from shifting when you insert rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this vlookup formula connected based on a range starting in row 11. When I insert a row into the range the vlookup pulls from it moves to the vlookup range to start from row 12. Is there a way to stop it from changing?

=IFNA(VLOOKUP(d24,Received_Calls!A$11:$F$427,2,FALSE),"")

Comment: you can lock `A11` with `$A$11` or just `A$11` since you are only asking about inserting rows.

Comment: But when I add a row to the Received Calls sheet it still will change the range to A$12 and I need it to still lookup within A11:F427

Comment: good point - use `INDIRECT` as @Andrew Swain suggested. You incorporate into the `vlookup` like this: `vlookup(d24,Indirect("Recieved_Calls!A$11:$F$427"),2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this on my portfolio NLV spreadsheet, where I have a Dashboard sheet, and subsequent individual accounts tabs (IRA, Roth, SEP, Trading, etc).

This has been a complete pain for longer than I care to say. But each week I would enter a new NLV row in each Account's sheet, and this would throw off the Dashboard totals, requiring me to adjust the Dashboard cell references.

Not sure if that makes any sense, but using INDIRECT has "fixed" an issue I've had with this for a while. Here is an example of what I did on the Dashboard line, for the IRA spreadsheet NLV cell:

```
=INDIRECT("IRA!E2")
```

Hope this helps. (This is for Google Sheets btw)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the INDIRECT function.  INDIRECT("A11") will always refer to A11 even if you insert rows above it.